# Checkbox Captcha

Tags: javascript, forms, checkbox, captcha

I'm initiating my first start-up. I can't stand attempting to read captchas when signing up for websites, don't want my users to.  I looked for alternatives, and I found the [checkbox captcha](http://uxmovement.com/forms/captchas-vs-spambots-why-the-checkbox-captcha-wins/).  How is this done, using JavaScript to load a checkbox, and validate it with the same code as would normally be used to make a sign up form?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked at the example linked from the article you posted.  At first glance, it seems like this can be easily bypassed.

The checkbox captcha works on the basis that spam-bots don't parse or use JavaScript code embedded in webpages.  Because of this, they will not find the captcha checkbox element within the form it is searching, and therefore will not send a post value for the checkbox along with the form, and on the server side, you would reject the form if the checkbox value wasn't sent.

The problem with this is:

- The checkbox name is always the same (`gasp_checkbox`)
- A bot could easily be "trained" to detect this javascript on your page and act accordingly
- Even if you output a random name and value that must be used for the checkbox, it could still be detected

The outcome of those 3 problems means that this is much easier to break than image captchas or other methods.  All a bot has to do when they submit your form is add: `gasp_checkbox=on` to their HTTP request.

That said, if you implement this for yourself on your own site, it is unlikely that any bots will able to get past it because its use is not widespread.

You could make it more secure by doing the following:

- Generate unique name/value pairs for the checkbox on the server side, and output those values in obfuscated javascript to the client
- Serve the script away from your form, preferably in an external javascript file that is generated by a script.
- Verify that the values sent for the checkbox match a pair that was previously generated, and not used before.

If you do those things, I think you could have an effective checkbox captcha.  If someone does catch on to it on your site, it may still be trivial to defeat, even with the above safeguards in place, but it may take a while, and still be effective for you most of the time.

Comment: then again, isn't it bad to have security through obscurity?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity, "The enemy knows the system."

Comment: Yeah, I agree it is, but I suppose the worst case scenario is that you start getting contact form spam or unwanted registrations so you can use the solution for some period of time until your site becomes a target of attack and you have to change to another solution.

Comment: It's funny reading this "early review" of the checkbox catcha - which turned out to do it's job quite well -- and now has been one-upped by [reCaptcha v3](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3) which returns a score indicating "likelihood of humanity" (paraphrased).